# KinectRegion HandPointer Cursor as mouse cursor in Awesomium Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, awesomium, kinect-sdk

I would like to use the kinect hand cursor as 'normal' mouse cursor. In the specific I want to be able to interact with the Awesomium browser object.

The problem is that no Awesomium Browser event is raised when the kinect hand cursor is (for example) over a link, or I do a click, or any other typical mouse event.

I modified the Control Basics-WPF example program that you can find in the example directory of the Kinect SDK

I am using c# visual studio 2012, Kinect SDK 1.7, Awesomium 1.7.1.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a month since this question's been asked, so perhaps you've already found your own solution.

In any case, I found myself in this scenario as well, and here was my solution:

Inside MainWindow.xaml, you'll need the Awesomium control inside a KinectRegion (from the SDK).

You'll have to somehow tell the SDK that you want a control to also handle hand events. You can do this by adding this inside MainWindow.xaml.cs on the Window_Loaded handler:

```
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerMoveHandler(webControl1, OnHandleHandMove);
KinectRegion.AddHandPointerLeaveHandler(webControl1, OnHandleHandLeave);
```

Elsewhere in MainWindow.xaml.cs, you can define the hand handler events. Incidentally, I did it like this:

```
    private void OnHandleHandLeave(object source, HandPointerEventArgs args)
    {
        // This just moves the cursor to the top left corner of the screen.
        // You can handle it differently, but this is just one way.
        System.Drawing.Point mousePt = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = mousePt;
    }

    private void OnHandleHandMove(object source, HandPointerEventArgs args)
    {
        // The meat of the hand handle method.
        HandPointer ptr = args.HandPointer;
        Point newPoint = kinectRegion.PointToScreen(ptr.GetPosition(kinectRegion));
        clickIfHandIsStable(newPoint); // basically handle a click, not showing code here
        changeMouseCursorPosition(newPoint); // this is where you make the hand and mouse positions the same!
    }

    private void changeMouseCursorPosition(Point newPoint)
    {
        cursorPoint = newPoint;
        System.Drawing.Point mousePt = new System.Drawing.Point((int)cursorPoint.X, (int)cursorPoint.Y);
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = mousePt;
    }
```

For me, the tricky parts were:
1. Diving into the SDK and figuring out which handlers to add. Documentation wasn't terribly helpful on this.
2. Mapping the mouse cursor to the kinect hand. As you can see, it involves dealing with System.Drawing.Point (separate from another library's Point) and System.Windows.Forms.Cursor (separate from another library's Cursor).